# Trying to find movies without directors in a ds on R

Tags: r

this is the code im trying to run to find rows where director is not equal to `NA`:

```r
nodir <- subset(x, director=="NA",
                    select = c(titles))
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `director=="NA"`. This logical comparison is defined to return `NA`. Because `NA` codes a missing value, `NA == NA` can be neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`. You want `is.na(director)`.

Comment: Since "NA" is a character value, director=="NA" will return `TRUE` for a director with that name (probably safe to assume there isn't one), `NA` for missing values, and `FALSE` for all other cases